# Updating model contains @DBRef [Spring-boot Angular]

Tags: angular, spring, mongodb, spring-boot, spring-data

On a spring boot project I'm using Spring Data MongoDB and I have classA that contains @DBRef I don't know how can I update it in the frontend I tried to update it all other variable are updated except classB whrereas for backend its working. Now I want someone to let me know how can I update Adresse.

```
public class User
{
@Id
private String id;

private String email

@DBRef
private Adresse adresse;
```

**User.Controller**

```
@PatchMapping("/update/{id}")
    public ResponseEntity<?> update(@Valid @RequestBody Utilisateur user, @PathVariable("id") String id){

        Optional<Utilisateur> userData = utilisateurRepository.findById(id);
       Utilisateur userToEdit = userData.get();
if(user.getAdresse()!=null){
               Adresse addr = new Adresse(user.getAdresse().getAdresse(), user.getAdresse().getVille(), user.getAdresse().getCode_postal()
                       , user.getAdresse().getRegion(), user.getAdresse().getPays());
               this.adresseRepository.save(addr);
               userToEdit.setAdresse(addr);
```

**user.service**

```
updateProfile(userData: any, id: string ): Observable<any> {
    return this.http.patch( API_URL + 'update/' + id, userData, httpOptions);
  }
```

**component.ts**

```
form: any = {};
  id: string;
  errorMessage = '';
  currentUser: any;

  constructor(private userservice: UserService, private route: ActivatedRoute, private router: Router, private token: TokenStorageService) { }

  ngOnInit() {
    this.currentUser = this.token.getUser();
  }
 onSubmit() {

    this.userservice.updateProfile(this.form, this.currentUser.id).subscribe(
      data => {
        console.log(data);

      },
      err => {
        this.errorMessage = err.error.message;
      }
    );
  }
```

**component.html**

```
<div class="form-group">
        <label>Address</label>
        <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder=""
                name="adresse"
                [(ngModel)]="form.adresse.adresse"
                required
                #adresse="ngModel">

      </div> <!-- form-group end.// -->
<div class="form-group col-md-6">
          <label>City</label>
      <input type="text" class="form-control"
             name="ville"
            [(ngModel)]="form.adresse.ville"
            required
            #ville="ngModel">
    </div> <!-- form-group end.// -->
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

form: UserInfo = {adresse {}};